# Toggle buttons on click

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura

i have a problem to figure out, how to toggle buttons in aura/lightning component.
I have two buttons with functions showMore and showLess.

The thing is, i want to only see button show more, and when i click on it, i want to show more button disappear and show less appear. And same with when i click on show less, switch show more on and less off

```
   <span class="show-more-button">
        <lightning:buttonIcon iconName="utility:macros"  alternativeText="Show more columns" onclick="{!c.showMore}" aura:id="show_more"/>
    </span>
    <span class="show-less-button">
        <lightning:buttonIcon iconName="utility:macros"  alternativeText="Show less columns" onclick="{!c.showLess}" aura:id="show_less"/>
    </span>
```

Comment: make use of `slds-hide`  to show and hide the respective button via component controller when button is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply [SLDS's slds-hide](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/utilities/visibility/) class and have an `aura:id` on the different buttons that need toggling and use the `$A.util` class to show/hide. You can refer to the following documentation - [Adding and Removing Styles](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_styles.htm)

```
<lightning:button onclick="{!c.toggleCSS}" label="Remove Style" />
<!--other buttons with some aura:id to toggle, init with class="slds-hide" for them not to be displayed -->
```

Controller.js

```
toggleCSS: function(cmp, event, helper) {
//cmp array can be fetched using cmp.find('auraId');
 //toggle using $A.Util calss
        $A.util.toggleClass(arr[cmp], 'slds-hide');


}
```